# Create a new column as the consensus of value within groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
Groups COL1         
G1     Unknown_RNA  
G1     Unknown_RNA  
G1     A            
G1     A            
G1     Unknown_RNA
G2     B
G2     A 
G2     B 
G3     Unknown_RNA
G3     A
G4     Unknown_RNA
G4     Unknown_RNA
G4     Unknown_RNA
```

Then I should keep the most representated value in `df$COL1` and put it in a `consensus_COL1`  column without taking into account the value `Unknown_RNA` (exept when there is only this value in the group.

Here I should get :

```
Groups COL1         consensus_COL1         
G1     Unknown_RNA  A
G1     Unknown_RNA  A
G1     A            A            
G1     A            A     
G1     Unknown_RNA  A 
G2     B            B
G2     A            B 
G2     B            B 
G3     Unknown_RNA  A
G3     A            A
G4     Unknown_RNA  Unknown_RNA 
G4     Unknown_RNA  Unknown_RNA 
G4     Unknown_RNA  Unknown_RNA
```

So far I only know how to keep the most representated value with :

```
 df %>% filter(COL1 != "") %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  add_count(COL1) %>%
  top_n(1, n) %>%
  distinct(consensus_COL1 = COL1) %>%
  right_join(df)
```

but I do not known how to add the `Unknown_RNA` issue

here are the data

```
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), 
    COL1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "Unknown_RNA"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this in a single pipe by `replace`ing the 'n' values to `NA` for those corresponding to 'Unknown_RNA'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
  add_count(Groups, COL1) %>% 
  mutate(n = replace(n, COL1 == 'Unknown_RNA', NA)) %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>% 
  mutate(consensus_COL1 = if(all(is.na(n))) 'Unknown_RNA' else COL1[which.max(n)])
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   Groups [4]
#   Groups COL1            n consensus_COL1
#   <fct>  <fct>       <int> <chr>         
# 1 G1     Unknown_RNA    NA A             
# 2 G1     Unknown_RNA    NA A             
# 3 G1     A               2 A             
# 4 G1     A               2 A             
# 5 G1     Unknown_RNA    NA A             
# 6 G2     B               2 B             
# 7 G2     A               1 B             
# 8 G2     B               2 B             
# 9 G3     Unknown_RNA    NA A             
#10 G3     A               1 A             
#11 G4     Unknown_RNA    NA Unknown_RNA   
#12 G4     Unknown_RNA    NA Unknown_RNA   
#13 G4     Unknown_RNA    NA Unknown_RNA
```

Comment: thank you very muc for your help and time

Comment: and what if I whant to add another exception such as ```Unknown_DNA``` for instance could I use something like ```%in% c('Unknown_RNA','Unknown_DNA')```?

Comment: In the `replace` you could convert use `COL %in% c(....)` to convert to NA

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to filter out `Unknown_RNA` after you get the count and then `left_join` this data with your original data frame and fill the `NA` with `Unknown_RNA`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<- structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                    2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), 
               COL1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                  3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "Unknown_RNA"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                            -13L))



df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(Groups) %>% 
  count(COL1) %>% 
  filter(COL1 != "Unknown_RNA") %>% 
  top_n(1, n) %>% 
  select(-n)-> tb_df
  
tb_df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   Groups [3]
#>   Groups COL1 
#>   <fct>  <fct>
#> 1 G1     A    
#> 2 G2     B    
#> 3 G3     A

df %>% 
  select(-2) %>% 
  left_join(tb_df) %>% 
  mutate(COL1 = COL1 %>% replace_na("Unknown_RNA")) %>% 
  rename(consensus_COL1 = COL1) %>% 
  mutate(COL1= df$COL1)
#> Joining, by = "Groups"
#>    Groups consensus_COL1        COL1
#> 1      G1              A Unknown_RNA
#> 2      G1              A Unknown_RNA
#> 3      G1              A           A
#> 4      G1              A           A
#> 5      G1              A Unknown_RNA
#> 6      G2              B           B
#> 7      G2              B           A
#> 8      G2              B           B
#> 9      G3              A Unknown_RNA
#> 10     G3              A           A
#> 11     G4    Unknown_RNA Unknown_RNA
#> 12     G4    Unknown_RNA Unknown_RNA
#> 13     G4    Unknown_RNA Unknown_RNA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your help it works like a charme